# Estou usando banco de dados JSON e tenho uma duvida?

Tags: ajax, banco-de-dados, json

Tenho um banco JSON de usuários, por exemplo, se eu atualizo meu nome de usuário via AJAX POST, clico em atualizar e chama o AJAX troca o valor com base no meu ID com PHP, tudo certinho.

Ai que entra a duvida no processamento PHP eu dou overwrite no banco, ou seja, salvo ele em cima do outro substituindo.

Numa demanda real de centenas de usuário atualizando o nome de usuário ao mesmo tempo no mesmo banco JSON e possível que aconteça bugs?

No SQL tem o Sqlquery que evita bugs (eu acho) mas em bancos em JSON Qual seria a forma mais inteligente de usar?

Somente processar esse overwhite depois que o usuário fechar a pagina? assim processando a atualização do banco somente uma vez em vez de cada vez que clicar em atualizar algum dado chamar o AJAX imediatamente?

Comment: JSON é um formato de codificação, não é um banco de dados. Você está gravando o JSON em um arquivo no servidor, é isso? Penso que o caminho natural é migrar para um banco NoSQL que representa os dados de forma hierárquica, muito semelhante ao JSON.

Comment: Uso JSON como banco de dados mesmo, no php dou file_get_contents('arquivojson') e armazeno em uma variavel depois passo o json_decode altero os valores que vem do front e salvo de novo com json_encode e com o file_put_contents('arquivojson');

Comment: Sei q talvez n seja o melhor jeito, e só uma duvida mesmo!

Comment: No caso de várias requisições ao mesmo tempo de um file_put_content() salvando o mesmo arquivo, como o PHP se comportaria?

Comment: Com certeza vai dar M. Na melhor das hipóteses, se dois ou mais processos escreverem o arquivo, só um sobrevive. Se todos estavam fazendo mudanças, só a mudança do processo sortudo sobrevive.

Comment: Não consigo entender quando o pessoal negativa essas perguntas, ele É INICIANTE, não sabe para o que funciona, se o site fosse para pessoas 100% experientes, não haveria perguntas e respostas. Minha opinião...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,

O `JSON` (acrônimo para: JavaScript Object Notation) é um formato leve de arquivos para troca de mensagens entre sistemas, e não um banco de dados. Sua popularidade se dá principalmente pela sua simplicidade de leitura e escrita em muitas linguagens. Quando vc deseja reescrever algo em um arquivo JSON você deve basicamente pegar o conteúdo antigo, mudar o que você deseja e reescrever o arquivo com o conteúdo novo. Não há como fugir disso.

Em um cenário com um grande número de dados, pegar o conteúdo antigo, editá-lo e escrevê-lo novamente pode levar alguns milissegundos. Entretanto isso significa x milissegundos por "query", oque impossibilita a utilização disso em um ambiente real. Por esse motivo o JSON não é a melhor opção na hora de substituir um banco de dados (e olha que ainda nem estamos falando de segurança). Contudo, se vc deseja mesmo assim utilizá-lo, tente quebrar em alguns arquivos, como tabelas. E na hora de executar "queries", procure diretamente o arquivo correspondente aquela "tabela". Essa solução não oferece nem a segurança e nem a velocidade de um banco de dados, mas é uma escolha sua utilizar ou não este método.

Espero ter ajudado, abraço.

Comment: E que meu projeto e pequeno... só quero um sistema de cadastro/login de users n acredito que vá ter mais de um user cadastrando simultaneamente

Comment: Entretanto não tenho o que perder usando um bd de "verdade",, vou marcar como resolvido muito obrigado